# Select2 Dropdown size is shrinking

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-select2

### Problem Statement:

Select2 Dropdown size is shrinking at some `div` but on some `div` it is coming up properly .

I've created Step-wizard form using Bootstrap 5. And have used Bootstrap 5 Accordion in one Step. When DOM is loaded only dropdown under Accordion is coming up properly other dropdowns are shrinking in size.

> Note: However, it is working in both the cases.

##### Dropdown under Bootstrap 5 Accordion:

[image: Dropdown under Bootstrap 5 Accordion]

##### Dropdown at other div in same page.

[image]

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <label for="gender" class="form-label">Gender</label>
    <select id="gender" onclick="getGender('gender')" class="gender form-select" ></select>
</body>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
        function getGender(type){
            $("."+type).select2({
                ajax: {
                url: "url",
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                            text: item.name,
                            id: item.id
                            }
                        })
                    };
                },
                cache: true,
                }
            });
        } 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            getGender('gender');
        });
</script>
```

Comment: please provide [complete code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce  your issue. it is impossible for us to help.

Comment: thanks for editing your post, but it is still not possible to reproduce your issue. as satated in my link, a minimal, reproducible example is necessary to help you out.